# Collect groupBy on deep property

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

```
private Map<String, Set<Square>> populateZuloSquare(List<Square> squares) {
    if (squares == null || squares.isEmpty()) {
        return emptyMap();
    }

    Map<String, Set<Square>> res = new HashMap<>();

    squares.stream()
        .filter(square -> {
            if (square.getZuloCodes().isEmpty()) {
                LOG("Ignored {}", square.id);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        })
        .forEach(square -> {
          square.getZuloCodes()
            .forEach(code -> {
                res.putIfAbsent(code, new HashSet<>());
                res.get(code).add(square);
            }));
        });

    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(res);
}
```

The code above receives a list of Squares, and those squares may contain ZuloCodes inside. The output should be a immutable Map zuloCode and value all the squares with that UniquePrefix.
As you can see I cannot figure out a way to remove the auxiliar collection res and make the code easily readable, is there a way to explode that collection into a [zuloCode, square] and then collect.groupBy ? Also that if inside the filter is so unreadable, how would you tackle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard approach is using `flatMap` before collecting using `groupingBy`, but since you need the original `Square` for each element, you need to map to an object holding both, the `Square` instance and the zulo code `String`.

Since there is no standard pair or tuple type in Java (yet), a work-around is to use a `Map.Entry` instance, like this

```
private Map<String, Set<Square>> populateZuloSquare0(List<Square> squares) {
    if (squares == null || squares.isEmpty()) {
        return emptyMap();
    }
    return squares.stream()
        .filter(square -> logMismatch(square, !square.getZuloCodes().isEmpty()))
        .flatMap(square -> square.getZuloCodes().stream()
            .map(code -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(code, square)))
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toSet())),
            Collections::unmodifiableMap));
}
private static boolean logMismatch(Square square, boolean match) {
    if(!match) LOG("Ignored {}", square.id);
    return match;
}
```

An alternative is to use a custom collector which will iterate over the keys:

```
private Map<String, Set<Square>> populateZuloSquare(List<Square> squares) {
    if (squares == null || squares.isEmpty()) {
        return emptyMap();
    }
    return squares.stream()
        .filter(square -> logMismatch(square, !square.getZuloCodes().isEmpty()))
        .collect(Collector.of(
            HashMap<String, Set<Square>>::new,
            (m,square) -> square.getZuloCodes()
                .forEach(code -> m.computeIfAbsent(code, x -> new HashSet<>()).add(square)),
            (m1,m2) -> {
                if(m1.isEmpty()) return m2;
                m2.forEach((key,set) ->
                    m1.merge(key, set, (s1,s2) -> { s1.addAll(s2); return s1; }));
                return m1;
            },
            Collections::unmodifiableMap)
        );
}
```

Note that this custom collector can be seen as a parallel capable variant of the following looping code:

```
private Map<String, Set<Square>> populateZuloSquare(List<Square> squares) {
    if (squares == null || squares.isEmpty()) {
        return emptyMap();
    }
    Map<String, Set<Square>> res = new HashMap<>();
    squares.forEach(square -> {
        if(square.getZuloCodes().isEmpty()) LOG("Ignored {}", square.id);
        else square.getZuloCodes().forEach(
            code -> res.computeIfAbsent(code, x -> new HashSet<>()).add(square));
    });
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(res);
}
```

which might not look so bad now, when you don’t need the code to be parallel capable…

Answer (score 0):

How about this. You may use `map` `merge` operation to get this thing done. I have updated the filter and simplified it too.

```
squares.stream().filter(s -> !s.getZuloCodes().isEmpty())
    .forEach(s -> s.getZuloCodes().stream().forEach(z -> res.merge(z, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s)),
        (s1, s2) -> Stream.of(s1, s2).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet()))));
```

Comment: it looks way more inefficient to do map merges instead of the putIfAbsent, as well as more unreadable also still keeps the auxiliar map

Comment: Can you please show us your bench marking results or point us to any site that states this. I have never seen such a thing mentioned in the documentation. Literally this approach is more declarative and immutable

Comment: Well no benchmarks but lets say 100 squares? Your scenario creates 1000 maps, 100 entries, 100 sets and 100 Arrays.asList(s) and merges them both on best and worst case. (you may consider singleList instead of asList) -
in mine: worst case there is no duplicates I'll create 1 map, 100 entries, 100 Sets, and do 100 set.add. Best case with 100% duplicates I'll create 1 map, 1 set, and do 100 adds ... I believe mine perform faster on average since the worst case scenario will be rare with my set of data, and yours may be more declarative, I may be wrong though it's just a rough feeling

Comment: sorry misspelled there 1000 should read 100 ... started with 1000 example but when I run out of chars removed a 0 of each, guess I missed one